# Remove application header

Tags: nginx, web-applications, http-headers

I compiled nginx with the headers_more_module and configured it to remove the

`Server: nginx`

from the response.

Now, the server name is not shown when curl -Ik example.com is given. But, when I ping the https URL of my site, I get the server name in the server response. How can the server name be completely removed from https responses also?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the http response header `Server`?

I am not clear what you mean by:

> configured it to remove the application name from the response.

Do you mean the server header, e.g `server: nginx`? Perhaps see: https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

The http and https configuration in NGINX may be controlled by two separate `server` blocks which means that they can both have different configurations. Can you confirm that you have applied the desired configuration to both server blocks.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to remove the Server: nginx header from the server response(updated the question). I configured it in the http block which includes all the server blocks. Should this be done separately on each server block?